# when i open my website the page automatically scroll down to the bottom,

Tags: html, css

If i open my page, it scroll to the bottom, i can resolve this by deleting the scroll behavior: smooth from html, but i need it, also i checked on other website and this don't happen, then it means there is something that doesn't work in my code so, why is this happening and how can i resolve it? P.S. if u also hve some advice to ho to make the code more clear, because i strted some week ago and i aam not very informed about the techniques.

```
html{
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
             
        }

        body {         
          background-image:url(img/sfondo2.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-size: cover;
          height: 100vh;
          
          -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
          -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox < 16 */
          -ms-animation: fadein 3s; /* Internet Explorer */
          -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 3s;
        }
        
        @keyframes fadein {
        from { opacity: 0; }
        to   { opacity: 1; }
        }

        /* Firefox < 16 */
        @-moz-keyframes fadein {
            from { opacity: 0; }
            to   { opacity: 1; }
        }
        /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
        @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
            from { opacity: 0; }
            to   { opacity: 1; }
        }

        /* Internet Explorer */
        @-ms-keyframes fadein {
            from { opacity: 0; }
            to   { opacity: 1; }
        }

        /* Opera < 12.1 */
        @-o-keyframes fadein {
            from { opacity: 0; }
            to   { opacity: 1; }
        }
        nav{
            color: white;
            
        }

        .navbar{
            float: right;
            list-style: none;    /*gets rid of bullet points*/ 
            text-align: left;
            /*padding: 0px -10px 0px -10px; */
             margin: 0;
        }

        .navbar > li {             /*max-width: 768px*/
            display:Inline-block;
            padding: 10px 9px 10px 9px;       /*nav bar text*/
        }

        #logo{
            float: left;
            width: 10%;
        }

        .navbar > li > a:hover {
            color: #eb4f34;
        }

        ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-size: 60px;
            
        }

        li{
            float: left;
            
        }

        li a{
            color: white;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            
        }

        li a:hover {
        color: #eb4f34;
        }

        .dwords{
            margin-top: 340px;     
            padding-left: 870px;      
            font-size: 70px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .button{
            color: #151D21;
            background: #ff7a7a;
            display: inline-flex;
            padding: 6px;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-right: 5%;
            margin-left: 5%;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 24px;
            
        }

        .pdetails{
            float: none;
        }
        
        #buttonn{
            text-align: center;
        }

        #Me{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 40px;
            margin: 5px;
            padding-top: 600px;
            padding-right: 100px;
            padding-left: 100px;
            padding-bottom: 600px ;
        }

        footer{
            background-attachment: scroll;
            background-position: 0% 0%;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0pt;
            display: block;
        }

        .clear{
            clear: both;
        }
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please check you link have any '#' ? and providing a code snippet would be great

Comment: Do you have something like `#foo-bar` in your url?

Comment: What's the actual HTML? Do you have a form field at the bottom of the page? The browser could be placing the cursor into that field and scrolling it into view.